# Listview doesn't size or place as I would expect

Tags: java, android, listview, dialog, scrollview

![enter image description here][1]I have a ListView and a ScrollView in a dialog. I want the ListView and ScrollView to fill up half the dialog. I only seem to achieve that with setting the width if the EditText in the ScrollView to 160dp. Is there anyway to do it, without specific dp?

Here is what happens with the following code:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxf-D6ENUTuAU21wclVpWkJUdTg/edit?usp=sharing

this is the ScrollView: search.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/primary_role"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Primary Role"
            android:textSize="18sp"
        />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/primary_assassin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Assassin"
        />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/primary_fighter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Fighter"
        />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/primary_jungle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Jungler"
        />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/primary_mage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Mage"
        />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/primary_marksman"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Marksman"
        />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/primary_support"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Support"
        />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/primary_tank"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Tank"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondary_role"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Secondary Role"
            android:textSize="18sp"
        />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/secondary_assassin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Assassin"
        />    

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/secondary_fighter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Fighter"
        />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/secondary_jungle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Jungler"
        />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/secondary_mage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Mage"
        />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/secondary_marksman"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Marksman"
        />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/secondary_support"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Support"
        />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/secondary_tank"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Tank"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

this is the custom list item I made: list_item.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my xml that the dialog uses to display: listview.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <include
        layout="@layout/search"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my mainActivity.java file

```
String[] example = {"example1", "example2", "example3"};

final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.listView);

dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

final ListView list_view = (ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.list);
final ArrayAdapter<String> list_array_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.iv, example);
list_view.setAdapter(list_array_adapter);

list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
    {
        // ListView Clicked item index
        int itemPosition = position;
        // ListView Clicked item value
        String itemValue = (String) list_view.getItemAtPosition(position);
        // Show Alert 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

This is what happens when I use this following code:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxf-D6ENUTuASE1KSmFZZDNkams/edit?usp=sharing

and this is what I want without having to use `android:layout_width = "160dp"` under the EditText.

Between the two pictures the only difference is under the EditText the width is 160dp in the second picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I needed to do. The only way I could make it work is create a TextView with no text that was centered horizontal and have the ListView toTheRight of that and the search.xml toTheLeft and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but I think you may be looking to contain these two Views in a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html), where you can declare that they should be rendered side-by-side by declaring one to be `android:layout_toRightOf` the other.  That is, add the line `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ScrollView"` to the XML for the ListView.

Comment: Yea srry. I was trying to post pictures and code and all but the mobile site and app wasn't letting me so I'll edit with fixes. Please be on the look out.